# Applying multiple parameters to callback without promises - node-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

In my little program, I try to unshorten an URL and then check if the link matches my pattern. If it does I want to further process it. But I also need to apply 3 parameter previously known.

My code feels very clunky dragging along all 3 parameters to each function. How can I streamline this without promises?

```
var request = require("request");

function expandUrl(shortUrl, a,b,c, callback) {
    request( { method: "HEAD", url: shortUrl, followAllRedirects: true },
        function (error, response) {
            callback(response.request.href, a,b,c);
        });
}


function checklink(unshortenedLink, a, b, c){
    matches = unshortenedLink.match(/twitter\.com\/\w+/g);
    if(matches){
        matches.forEach(function(result){
            process_twitter_link(result, a, b, c);
        });
    }
}

function process_twitter_link(link, a, b ,c ){
    console.log(link + " " + a + " " + b + " " + c);
    // std.out: twitter.com/StackJava param_a param_b param_c
}

expandUrl("https://t.co/W0DA8WVpmO", "param_a", "param_b", "param_c", checklink);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your problem is in the callback and there is asynchronousness going on I would recommend to use Promises:

```
function expandUrl(shortUrl) {
    var deferred = Deferred.create();
    request( { method: "HEAD", url: shortUrl, followAllRedirects: true },
        function (error, response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.request.href,);
        });
    return deferred.promise();
}

expandUrl(shortenedUrl).done(function (resolved_url) {
    checklink(resolved_url, "param_a", "param_b", "param_c");
});
```

This removes the 3 parameters from `expandUrl`, but they remains on `checklink`.

---

I'm not sure if Node.js has a promises modules. `request` might return a promise in-and-of-itself. You might be able to just chain a `.then` and return just the resolved url that way.

---

Without promises:

```
function expandUrl(shortUrl, callback) {
    request( { method: "HEAD", url: shortUrl, followAllRedirects: true },
        function (error, response) {
            callback(response.request.href);
        });
}

expandUrl(shortenedUrl, function (resolved_url) {
    checklink(resolved_url, "param_a", "param_b", "param_c");
});
```

Comment: There is a deferred module, and this looks very clean. But I specifically tried to find a solution without promises, because I want to learn how to use callbacks without them first.

Comment: I see, please see my updated answer. Promises are far preferred over callbacks, I'm hoping you'll learn why while working with the callback method. Good luck :)

Comment: Any promises module worth using will have auto-promisification of callback APIs. And if you are going to do manual promisification then you should not swallow errors like that.

Comment: This looks _promising_ ;) Although doesn't work out of the box. Did you keep the original `checklink` function unchanged in this example?

Comment: I can't decide which answer to accept, this seems like it has the best control-flow. But the bind version from Andreas looks a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

What if you'd wrap them in an object?

```
function expandUrl(shortUrl, context, callback) {
    request( { method: "HEAD", url: shortUrl, followAllRedirects: true },
        function (error, response) {
            callback(response.request.href, context);
        });
}


function checklink(unshortenedLink, context){
    matches = unshortenedLink.match(/twitter\.com\/\w+/g);
    if(matches){
        matches.forEach(function(result){
            process_twitter_link(result, context);
        });
    }
}

function process_twitter_link(link, context ){
    console.log(link + " " + context.a + " " + context.b + " " + context.c);
    // std.out: twitter.com/StackJava param_a param_b param_c
}

expandUrl("https://t.co/W0DA8WVpmO", {a: "param_a", b: "param_b", c: "param_c"}, checklink);
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. 1 unwanted parameter isn't so different from 3. The goal here is to unbind the 3 parameters from `expandURL`.

Comment: Ok, this looks slightly better, but we are still dragging it along all functions, just packaged in an object now. I feel like there might be a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to partially apply the callback:

```
var request = require("request");

function expandUrl(shortUrl, callback) {
    request( { method: "HEAD", url: shortUrl, followAllRedirects: true },
        function (error, response) {
            callback(response.request.href);
        });
}


function checklink(a, b, c, unshortenedLink){
    matches = unshortenedLink.match(/twitter\.com\/\w+/g);
    if(matches){
        matches.forEach(function(result){
            process_twitter_link(result, a, b, c);
        });
    }
}

function process_twitter_link(link, a, b ,c ){
    console.log(link + " " + a + " " + b + " " + c);
    // std.out: twitter.com/StackJava param_a param_b param_c
}

var checklinkWithParams = checklink.bind(null, "param_a", "param_b", "param_c");

expandUrl("https://t.co/W0DA8WVpmO", checklinkWithParams);
```

Note: the partially applied arguments will come first.

Comment: You can solve the argument order issue by passing the anonymous function: `function (resolved_url) { checklink(resolved_url, "param_a", "param_b", "param_c"); }` instead. I think this is also more readable as bind is typically a little hard to understand.

Comment: That's right, especially considering that the first argument is usually reserved for the error.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to reduce the repetition a bit would be to use `.bind()`:

```
var request = require("request");

function expandUrl(shortUrl, callback) {
    request({ method: "HEAD", url: shortUrl, followAllRedirects: true },
        function (error, response) {
            callback(response.request.href);
        });
}


function checklink(a, b, c, unshortenedLink){
    matches = unshortenedLink.match(/twitter\.com\/\w+/g);
    if(matches){
        matches.forEach(function(result){
            process_twitter_link(result, a, b, c);
        });
    }
}

function process_twitter_link(link, a, b ,c ){
    console.log(link + " " + a + " " + b + " " + c);
    // std.out: twitter.com/StackJava param_a param_b param_c
}

expandUrl("https://t.co/W0DA8WVpmO", checklink.bind(null, "param_a", "param_b", "param_c"));
```

However I would say `checklink()` doesn't need access to a,b,c, but that might depend in if you consider that one and process_twitter_link tightly coupled or not. If they're not, the following is possible:

```
var request = require("request");

function expandUrl(shortUrl, callback) {
    request({ method: "HEAD", url: shortUrl, followAllRedirects: true },
        function (error, response) {
            callback(response.request.href);
        });
}


function checklink(iterator){
    return function (unshortenedLink) {
        matches = unshortenedLink.match(/twitter\.com\/\w+/g);
        if(matches){
            matches.forEach(iterator);
        }
    }
}

function process_twitter_link(a, b ,c ){
    return function (link) {
        console.log(link + " " + a + " " + b + " " + c);
    };
}

expandUrl("https://t.co/W0DA8WVpmO", checklink(process_twitter_link("param_a", "param_b", "param_c")));
```

Voilà, a,b,c are only used in one place!

(Note that this code is not tested but should work in theory)

Comment: Yes, a,b,c don't need accecss to `checklink()`, I was just doing it, because I didn't find a way without doing that. I'm trying to understand your code now, since I think it's the cleanest for now.  What's the value of `iterator`? Is it the `process_twitter_link()` with paramenters?

Comment: Yes iterator is process_twitter_link supplied to checklink with the params prepared. Actually I see now that I'm a bit inconsistent in using .bind(), so I'm gonna update the answer to not use it (and make checklink return a function instead, just like process_twitter_link).